# TYPO3 Custom Content fields on save database error

Tags: database, save, typo3, field

I added  some content Fields which looks as it follows;

```
$temporaryColumnHC = array(
    'my_type' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label'   => 'My Type',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => array(
                array('Bar', 'bar'),
                array('Pie', 'pie'),
                array('Donut', 'donut'),
                array('Line', 'line'),
                array('Bar 2', 'bar2'),
                array('Bar 3', 'bar3'),
                array('Bubble', 'bubble'),
            )
        )
    ),

    'my_suffix' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label'   => 'My Label Suffix',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 10,
            'max' => 20
        )
    ),
    'my_source_url' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label'   => 'Source URL',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'inputLink'
        )
    ),
    'my_source' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label'   => 'Source Text',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 15
        )
    ),

);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    $temporaryColumnHC
);
```

but on save I get the following error

```
error  [1620]: Unknown column 'suffix' in 'field list'
```

What I have to do that this fields is saved in database

Comment: You have `my_suffix` in your TCA but `suffix` in your error. Could it be that there is a wrong field defined?

Comment: sorry it is just wrong copy paste If I add the columns manually all works fine. But how can say Typo3 to do it automatically

Comment: have you missed to create the fields in the DB table? you need to create a file `ext_tables.sql` in the root of your extension where your new fields are created when your extension gets activated.

Comment: As @BerndWilkeπφ pointed out `ext_tables.sql` needs to have a proper definition. You have to use `CREATE TABLE ( suffix VARCHAR(20) )` format btw. TYPO3 internally converts it. In addition if the ext. is activated already you can update the database schema e.g. via install tool.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already as a comment, TYPO3 complains that the column is missing in the Database.
Your extension should provide an `ext_tables.sql` which extends the Database Schema. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FilesAndLocations/Index.html#ext-tables-sql for further information.

The file always contains `CREATE TABLE` statements, which will be converted by TYPO3 do update the schema.
Updating the schema can be done through the install tool of TYPO3, or tools like TYPO3 console via command line.